# Debug version of vc++ project compains of missing msvcr80d.dll

Tags: visual-c++

I have a native c++ program exe which builds successfully and runs successfully in the release version. However when i try to run debug exe, it throws an exception "This application has failed to start because MSVCP80D.dll was not found. RE-installing the application may fix the proble,

Comment: Why are you running the debug version? The release version works fine. You're not supposed to deploy the debug version. Your development machine already has the necessary debug DLLs installed.

Comment: This is not for deployment..But i want to debug the application on my developer system and because of this issue I am unable to debug. I do have VS2005 installed and corresponding vc++ redestributable for 2005..is there anything distributable that i should be installing for debug?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you have VS 2005 installed with all of the C++ development tools, you should definitely have all the necessary debug libraries. There's something corrupted in your install. I suggest reinstalling VS and/or the Windows SDK.

Comment: Yes..I agree..Strangely enough, i see this issue in other development system as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try statically linking the runtime libraries if you need to run a debug build on a PC that does not have Visual Studio installed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: This is not a solution. Static linking is not really a good idea in general, and if you can compile a statically-linked application, then you surely have the necessary DLLs available on your machine. This advice is as good as telling someone to buy a new computer when theirs starts running slow.

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend static linking or deploying debug builds. It's sometimes useful to run debug builds on test systems without Visual Studio though, which was my interpretation of the question. I agree with the later comments above that if this problem occurs on the Visual Studio machine, then there is a different configuration issue.

Comment: Yes the problem was occuring on the Vistual studio machine on a deveoper system rather and it was because the debug configuration properties werent correct.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you don't have the DEBUG version of the C/C++ runtime on that machine, only the RELEASE builds. Debug builds are meant only for development and debugging. You should not install/distribute them, only Release builds. And you should install the appropriate redistributable with the VC++ runtimes.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. This is not for deployment..But i want to debug the application on my developer system and because of this issue I am unable to debug. I do have VS2005 installed and  corresponding vc++ redestributable for 2005..is there anything distributable that i should be installing for debug?

Comment: no, there is no one, but you can copy them manually from the VC++ installation folder. and you can use depends.exe (www.dependencywalker.com) to check what are the DLLs your app needs